# Replace the key in the array in php codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string which i am spitting using explode functionality. Code Snippet is shown below

```
$string = "2017167637/ 43/ 42/ 38/ 46/ 41/ 40/ 39";
                                $tags = (explode("/",$string));
                                print_r($tags);
                                foreach ($tags as $key)
                                $invoicedata[] = (object)$key;

                                echo '<pre>'; print_r($invoicedata); exit;
```

The Output what i am getting right now is

```
 Array ( [0] => 2017167637 [1] => 43 [2] => 42 [3] => 38 [4] => 46 [5] => 41 [6] => 40 [7] => 39 )
 Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [scalar] => 2017167637
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [scalar] =>  43
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [scalar] =>  42
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [scalar] =>  38
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [scalar] =>  46
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [scalar] =>  41
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [scalar] =>  40
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [scalar] =>  39
    )
```

But the actual output what i need is in place of [scalar] i need [invoice]. How to do it? Any help appreciated.

Actual output what i need is shown below

```
  Array ( [0] => 2017167637 [1] => 43 [2] => 42 [3] => 38 [4] => 46 [5] => 41 [6] => 40 [7] => 39 )
  Array
  (
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [invoice] => 2017167637
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [invoice] =>  43
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [invoice] =>  42
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [invoice] =>  38
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [invoice] =>  46
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [invoice] =>  41
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [invoice] =>  40
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [invoice] =>  39
    )

)
```

I tried with adding $invoice['invoice'] but it did not worked so how to get the desired output any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code. Try this.

```
$string = "2017167637/ 43/ 42/ 38/ 46/ 41/ 40/ 39";
                            $tags = (explode("/",$string));
                            print_r($tags);

                            foreach ($tags as $key=>$value)
                            {
                            $invoicedata[$key] = new stdClass();    
                            $invoicedata[$key]->invoice = $value;
                            }
                            echo '<pre>'; print_r($invoicedata); exit;
```

Comment: Hi @ShreyasBandimat I have edited my code. Please check now. :)